# BeautifulSoup cannot find any <a> tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the website here: ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/daily-index/. Using the code as shown below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import urllib.request
html = urllib.request.urlopen("ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/daily-index/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(line, "lxml")
soup.a # or soup.find_all('a') neither of them works
#return None.
```

Please help, I am really frustrated by this. My suspicion is that the  tag is causing the problem. The site's Html looks well formated (matched tags), so I am lost as to why BeautifulSoup doesn't find anything. Thanks

Comment: And what makes you think you are getting HTML from that URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/daily-index/` URL leads to a FTP directory, not an HTML page.

Your *browser* could generate HTML based on the FTP directory contents, but the server does not send you HTML when you load that resource with `urllib.request`.

You probably want to use the [`ftplib` module](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/ftplib.html) directly instead to read the directory listing, or inspect the return value of `urlopen(...).read()` first.